# Present value minus previous value (python)

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I want to subtract the present value by the previous value in each line and whenever there is N/A, it will copy the previous available value and subtract this by the previous available value.

When I run the codes below, I get the following message: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'value'. Could anyone please help fix it?

```
import pandas as pd

from pandas import ExcelWriter

from pandas import ExcelFile

df = pd.read_excel('ccy_test.xlsx')

X = df.iloc[3:, 1:]

df.fillna(method='pad')

count_row = df.shape[0]

count_col = df.shape[1]

z = df.value[:count_row,1:count_col] - df.value[:count_row,:count_col-1]

dz = pd.DataFrame(z)
```

[Sample File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gp422p88ygb4n0u/ccy_test.csv?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues with the code you posted. The example file is a `csv` file, so you need to refer to "ccy_test.csv". The column `Value` only contains 0's, so for this example I use the column `Open`.

Furthermore, I added to your `read_csv`:

1. `index_col=0` -> makes the first column `dates` the index
2. `parse_dates=[0]` -> parse the dates as dates (instead of strings)
3. `skiprows=3` -> don't read the first rows, as they are not part of the table
4. `header=0` -> read the first row (after the skip) as column names

So:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('ccy_test.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=[0], skiprows=3, header=0)

df = df.fillna(method='pad')

df['Difference'] = df.Open.diff()

print(df)
```

The output:

```
                        Open     High      Low  Value  Volume  Difference
Dates                                                                    
2018-03-01 09:30:00  0.83064  0.83121  0.83064    0.0     0.0         NaN
2018-03-01 09:31:00  0.83121  0.83128  0.83114    0.0     0.0     0.00057
2018-03-01 09:32:00  0.83128  0.83161  0.83126    0.0     0.0     0.00007
2018-03-01 09:33:00  0.83161  0.83169  0.83161    0.0     0.0     0.00033
2018-03-01 09:34:00  0.83169  0.83169  0.83145    0.0     0.0     0.00008
```

Comment: Many thanks again. How can I do it across all columns pls?

Comment: You can just add columns with `df['new_column'] = df['column_to_calculate_difference_on'].diff()`

Comment: one minor follow up question, I'd like to shift the data that contains 'difference' (diff Open, Close, Value etc) column to another table (e.g. called 'ds'). How may I do it pls?

Comment: `ds = df[['a','b']]` where a, b, etc are your difference column names

Answer (score 1):

`df.fillna(method='pad')` by default won't *change* your dataframe, you need to redefine it with `df = df.fillna(method='pad')`.

Comment: many thanks. I have redefined it as suggested, but the error message is still ''DataFrame' object has no attribute 'value''. How may I fix it pls?